# Block on result of `async` method within a normal (sync) method

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

Say I have an async 'core' in my algorithm that is *meant* to return a final result.

And some sync parts that have to run before and after. Like:

```py
async def algo_async(x):
    await ...
    return result
def run():
    x = prepare()
    r = ???(algo_async(x)) #< What here?
    post(r)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Async function can be (and should be) runned by [event loop](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html), for example:

```
def run():
    x = prepare()
    r = asyncio.run(algo_async(x))
    post(r)
```

(If you have Python < 3.7 use `asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(algo_async(x))` instead of `asyncio.run`)

---

Note, however, that main reason to make function async in the first place is an ability to run it concurrently with other async functions. When you run async function inside synchronous function, you lose this ability and all related benefits.

That's why usually people make event loop running entry point of whole program and use make all functions that need to run async function async also.

Comment: For the note: consider that the async algo itself runs several things concurrently. My whole issue is with explicitly sequencing part of the pipeline, while not making the `main` function itself async (because I can't). Your solution is simple, and _does_ work in a script, but I can't get it to work in a Jupyter environment (using IPython 7.x, which seems to react weirdly to async code?). Any help appreciated!

Comment: @Narfanar in case problem you have is "asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop" it is discussed [here](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3397). Solution from [this comment](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3397#issuecomment-383452306) solved issue for me: https://i.imgur.com/oTpuaRu.png